# Retrieving 'int' field from MongoDB Document throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, mongodb

I know **MongoDB** field name is case sensitive, at least while retrieving a value for the field. I have following Java Program.

```
public class SimpleDocument {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = new Document("String","Aeroplane").append("int", 20);

        String s1 = doc.getString("String");
        String s2 = doc.getString("string");
        System.out.println("s1="+s1+" and s2="+s2);

        int i1 = doc.getInteger("int");
        int i2 = doc.getInteger("Int"); //throws NullPointerException
        System.out.println("i1="+i1+" and i2="+i2);
    }
}
```

The first Sysout displays output as expected i.e., *s1="Aeroplane"* and *s2=null*. But the 2nd Sysout does not display anything as the line just above it throws a **NullPointerException** which I can't understand.

Can anybody explain the logic?

Comment: Autounboxing. What goes in an `int` if the field `Int` is missing?

Comment: @chrylis, as shown my document holds value 20 in a field 'int'.

Comment: Yes, and nothing in field `Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document doc = new Document("String","Aeroplane").append("int", 20);

String s1 = doc.getString("String");
String s2 = doc.getString("string");
System.out.println("s1="+s1+" and s2="+s2);

int i1 = doc.getInteger("int");
int i2 = doc.getInteger("Int"); //throws NullPointerException
System.out.println("i1="+i1+" and i2="+i2);
```

For `s1` you are reading in `"String"` which is equal to `"Aeroplane"`.

- `s1="Aeroplane";`

For `s2` you are reading in `"string"` which will equal to `null` (doesn't exist in your document). Strings are objects and are NOT primitive data types, so they are able to store `null` inside of them.

- `s2=null;`

For `i1` you are reading in `"int"` which is equal to `20`

- `i1=20;`

For `i2` you are reading in `"Int"` which will equal to `null` (doesn't exist in your document). Then you are trying to store `null` inside of a `int` primitive. So you will have an exception.

What you need to do is:

```
Integer i2 = doc.getInteger("Int");
```

This will prevent the exception from being thrown, and will allow `i2=null;`

Comment: Thank you  @user123. This should be acceptable answer for the correct explanation. Seems being new user, SO does not consider my vote even I vote it up.